# How to construct sunburst charts in gnumeric

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, gnumeric

I'm trying to arrange species into a sunburst (multilevel pie or ring) chart that summarizes their numbers at genus, family level and so on. I cannot seem to realize that with gnumeric (and neither with LibreOffice calc for that matter) as I happen to have too many "dimensions".

Here is an example of the gnumeric manual that shows how to use a sunburst chart:
[image]

My data however comes in such format that I don't have the same entry across all rings:

```
Kingdom  Phylum  Class  Species_count
Animalia    Arthropoda  Insecta 2
Animalia    Arthropoda  Malacostraca    13
Animalia    Bryozoa Gymnolaemata    59
Bacteria    Cyanobacteria   Cyanophyceae    8
```

Is it possible to realize that within gnumeric or LibreOffice?

Comment: Maybe QtiPlot can do it.

Comment: You're trying to use a glove as a shoe: you have lots of denominations and one column of numbers.  A sunburst chart has lots of data and one column title and one row title.
No way to do this in LibreOffice or Gnumeric.  You need specialised plotting software.